# Change language ICS spell correction (red dotted line)

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, languages, spell-check

I've upgraded my i9000 to Android 4.0 using CM9. I've found a major annoyance though. I've enabled spell-checking on my phone (the fancy one, with the red, dotted lines), but it appears to be available only in English, and 4 other languages. See this image:

[image]

When I switch my entire system language to Dutch, the dotted line just disappears. I've Googled around and learned that Android.com [officially states](http://www.android.com/about/ice-cream-sandwich/): "For specialized features or additional languages, you can now download and install third-party dictionaries, spell-checkers, and other text services."

However, I haven't been able to find language packs like these. I'm dying for one, and find it hard to imagine that months after the launch of 4.0 not a single language pack has been made.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Much appreciated!

Comment: did you try: Android keyboard settings > Add-on dictionaries > Nederlands .. ?

Comment: Yes I did, but the setting wasn't really there up until a week ago or so (CM9 4.0.4). My stock Transformer 4.0.3 still doesn't have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently on Cyanogenmod 4.0.4 and Dutch has been added. I don't know where it came from, but it works like a charm.