# Can Galaxy S2 ICS be updated to enable spell-checker without rooting?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, spell-check

I've read that Samsung disabled the ICS spell-checker by removing it from the settings application.  Can it be re-added/enabled without rooting the phone?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Android ICS spell checker does not know how to spell (English)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23607/android-ics-spell-checker-does-not-know-how-to-spell-english), spell-checker seems to be enabled [but there's some issues].

Right now, I'm on Samsung Galaxy S2 ICS [using CyanogenMod], and there is a checkbox to enable Spelling correction. When I was using stock ICS, I could turn off spelling / auto-correction, but it might be because I was also using a 3rd-party keyboard [GO SMS Pro]